# setSupportBackgroundTintList states not working

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I created a MyButton class which extends AppCompat button. In my onstructors I execute this code:

```
    int[][] states = new int[][]{
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
    };

    int[] colors = new int[]{
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tint),
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary),
    };

    setSupportBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(states, colors));
```

Unfortunately the states are not working. The button only shows the enabled color. I'm using the newest appcompat libs and also tried older ones

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'  //also tried 23.0.1
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'        //also tried 23.0.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

States are matched in the order that they are defined. So, `android.R.attr.state_enabled` will be matched *before* `android.R.attr.state_pressed`.

Since the button is enabled, the first positive match will be against `android.R.attr.state_enabled` and color `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tint)` will be chosen. Since, a positive match has been found, *it does not matter if the button is pressed or not*.

The quickest way to sort this out is to place `android.R.attr.state_pressed` before `android.R.attr.state_enabled`. State matching will go as follows:

- button is currently pressed --> state `android.R.attr.state_pressed` will be checked against and a positive match will be found --> color `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary)` will be used.
- button is currently **not** pressed --> state `android.R.attr.state_pressed` will be checked against and the check will fail --> state `android.R.attr.state_enabled` will be checked against and a positive match will be found --> color `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tint)` will be used.

This should work:

```
int[][] states = new int[][]{
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, // pressed
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} // enabled
};

int[] colors = new int[]{
        ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary),
        ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tint)
};

setSupportBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(states, colors));
```